# Extracting water out of silica gel

Tags: water, material-science

From my preliminary research I've learned that desiccants are a good (best?) method to absorb water from air. Assuming I'm using silica gel (or kitchen salt, or rice) then what is the best way to extract the water out of the desiccant?

Comment: This strikes me as a chemistry question, but if anyone would like to make an argument that it is in fact physics, I'm willing to listen and reopen it if appropriate.

Comment: The desiccants mentioned aonly use physics! I'd recommend to read about the "borderline" between physics and chemistry.

Comment: @Georg: if you have a resource in mind, I would appreciate a reference.

Comment: This border is simple: chemistry deals about cases of compunds being made from elements or react with each other. Short: reactions are chemistry. To know what happens when water is absorbed by silica gel, one needs to learn a little bit of chemistry. :=)

Comment: Nevertheless I agree in the closing, just because this question is about "Practical by Uncle Joe"

Answer (score 2):

Heating the silica will drive out the water, I forget it's melting point but you aren't goign to get there!